# How to track redux event in google tag manager debugger?

Tags: redux, react-redux, google-tag-manager

I have create a small app using react and redux. Now i have implement google tag manager to my app and have connected all my redux actions to google tag manager events.

REDUX ACTION :

[image]

Google tag manager event:
[image]

Now when i click on book my redux action is getting triggered and also gtm logging is working but nothing is happening in google tag manager debugger.

[image]

Can anybody help me how to track redux events in gtm

Answer (score 0):

Not hugely familiar with redux, but your screenshot shows that there is no "event" key in the dataLayer (which GTM needs to update its internal variables from the data you push), and b) it says "there are no tags in this container", so you either did not set up tracking tags or forgot to publish them.